# How to add two TextInputEditText in one TextInputLayout

Tags: android

I want to add two TextInputEditText in one TextInputLayout to be like this:
[image]

I've tried to do like this:

```
<LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
            android:layout_weight="0.8"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/material_margin">

            <android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
                android:id="@+id/profile_height_edit_txt"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="start"
                android:hint="@string/growth"
                android:inputType="number"
                android:maxLength="3"/>
        </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
            android:layout_weight="0.2"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
        </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

    </LinearLayout>
```

But I've got the space between two `TextInputEditText`s (marked with red line)
[image]

Maybe somebody know the better soluiton for this (without any space between two TextInputEditTexts)

Thank you!

Comment: Remove backgrounds from textinputlayout and textinputedittext with transparent color and add a view on bottom as a line with height 1dp and background that you want, and to put at the end 'kg' with an textview. If you want and example with xml, i can do it tomorrow.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/MB_reading_layout_wrapper">

    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
        android:id="@+id/MB_reading_layout_wrapper_1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/MB_reading_text_1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:hint="Weight"
            android:inputType="numberDecimal"
            android:textSize="20sp" />
    </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:text="kg" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

`Instead of using a TextView, you may use an EditText.`

[image: Example]

Comment: nice solution, thank you. But "kg" will be a bit higher than input text. I will try to set the similar indent from the line

Comment: doesn't seem a good solution as text will mix with kg